# How can I manually invoke the function signature preview?

Tags: autocompletion, previewing

If I am coding in PHP and I type out a PHP built-in function (e.g. `explode()`)  vims standard omni-complete would normally provide a function signature in a preview window.
I recently installed a couple of plugins and now the function signature preview doesnt seem to work, is there any way to manually invoke this preview window with function signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could go to the end of the function and and press `<c-x><c-o>` if  `'completeopt'` has `menuone` set. However this will add an extra paren at the end of the function.

I use the following snippet in my `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim` file:

```
function! s:PHPQuickMan(word)
  if !exists('g:php_builtin_functions')
    call phpcomplete#LoadData()
  endif
  let word = a:word . '('
  if !get(b:, 'php_quick_man_color', get(g:, 'php_quick_man_color', 1))
    echo word . get(g:php_builtin_functions, word, ' can not be found')
  else
    let sig = get(g:php_builtin_functions, word, '')
    if sig == ''
      echohl WarningMsg
      echo word . ' can not be found'
      echohl None
    else
      echon word
      for part in split(matchstr(sig, '.*\ze|\s\+\w\+$'), '\<')
        echohl Directory
        let w = matchstr(part, '\v^(int|array|mixed|callable|object|string|bool|void|resource)')
        echon w
        echohl None
        echon strpart(part, len(w))
      endfor
      echon ") | "
      echohl WarningMsg
      echon matchstr(sig, '|\s\+\zs\w\+$')
      echohl None
    endif
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <buffer> K :call <SID>PHPQuickMan(expand('<cword>'))<cr>
```

This leverages the php's omni-complete database to print out at the bottom of the screen the function signature when you press `K` on a function.

For more help see:

```
:h 'completeopt'
:h compl-omni
:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-O
:h K
:h 'keywordprg'
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for this! I can get it to work for straight functions, but not for methods, e.g. it doesnt work on `$dbh->prepare($sql)` whereas vims builtin omni complete does provide assistance for `prepare()` - when its called on an object (but wont if its not used in an object context)

Comment: I should have been more clear it uses Vim builtin omni complete for functions via `g:php_builtin_functions`.

Comment: thats the weird thing, vim's builtin onmi-complete - for methods -  *does* work, but when I invoke the method signature with your snippet it doesnt work. just to repeat: you snippet works fine on builtin *functions* - its just methods that dont seem to work

Comment: Since the snippet uses `g:php_builtin_functions` it has no support for methods, just functions. Please feel free to improve upon it to work for methods calls